# karnaugh-map, unable to connect specific cells

Tags: diagrams, karnaugh

I need to use the `\usepackage{karnaugh-map}` to draw some karnaugh-map.
In this table:

```
\begin{karnaugh-map}

    \manualterms{1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1}

\end{karnaugh-map}
```

I would like to operate the logical connection like in the photo

[image]

But I really don't know how to operate the link between 0 and 8, and also between 3 and 11. Is there  anyway to obtain something like in the picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the manual (see [karnaugh-map](https://ctan.org/pkg/karnaugh-map)) you find how to draw implicants in the section Implicants;-).

For your example you can do something like

```
\begin{karnaugh-map}
  \manualterms{1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1}
  \implicant{13}{11}
  \implicant{15}{10}
  \implicantedge{0}{0}{8}{8}
  \implicantedge{3}{3}{11}{11}
\end{karnaugh-map}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you... I read the document, but, stupidly, I didn't noticed that the correct command to select the edges was \implicantedge.